# What is the difference between flight watch and home reserve?

Tags: airline-operations, terminology

Can anyone explain the difference between 'flight watch' and 'home reserve' with regards to flight and duty periods. 
This is in regards to a charter operation, where crew members are on standby at the local crew house (home reserve), and are required to keep track of aircraft via satellite tracking while on standby (flight watch).

I am unsure what the distinction would be according to the law, as flight watch would still be considered as a duty period, as with standby time. Would the two be classified together as duty periods?

The reason this is of importance is crew members can do 12 hour shifts of **Standby time** , however the law has a different max time for **duty periods**

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: This is for West Africa, under ANAC. They are structured as per FAA, however I am not looking so much as per the law regarding this, as per the generally accepted definition differences between Flight watch, Home reserve and Standby